# Datatable not allowing me to edit cells, have setting `editable = 'cell'`

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am working on a shiny app that generates a DT::datatable. The intended flow is that an end user can amend one of the fields called 'spend' and once they add a custom spend amount, the estimated profit is calculate off that new spend.

Code blow generates the app with dummy data. When you run the app and click the tab 'dh' the datatable shows. I can double click on any cell in the second column (spend) but I cannot 'enter' it, pressing enter does nothing.

[image]

Here is the code to generate the app:

```
pacman::p_load(shiny, tidyverse, shinydashboard, lubridate, scales, DT)

# generates an example df based on inputed budgets
create_sample_df <- function(budgets) {
  data.frame(cohort = seq('2020-10-01' %>% ymd, '2021-12-31' %>% ymd, by = '1 days')) %>% 
    mutate(Quarter = quarter(cohort, with_year = T)) %>% 
    add_count(Quarter) %>% 
    mutate(DailyBudget = budgets[Quarter %>% as.character] %>% unlist / n) %>% 
    group_by(Quarter) %>% 
    mutate(Revenue = DailyBudget + rnorm(n(), mean = 0, sd = DailyBudget / 5)) %>% 
    summarise(Spend = sum(DailyBudget),
              Revenue = sum(Revenue),
              .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    mutate(Profit = dollar(Revenue - Spend),
           Payback = percent(Revenue / Spend),
           Spend = dollar(Spend),
           Revenue = dollar(Revenue)) %>% 
    mutate(Quarter = as.character(Quarter)) # do this last keep ordering of quarters
}



# render DT
render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}


# UI ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Velocity Spend & Return Calculator')
HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  menuItem("dh", tabName = "dh", icon = icon("dashboard"))
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dh",
            h2("DH Estimator"),
            HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations"),
            DT::DTOutput('budgets_df_dh')
            
    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Initial budgets, eventually set to come from dropdowns or user input
  budgets <- list(
    '2020.4' = 1000000,
    '2021.1' = 1000000,
    '2021.2' = 1000000,
    '2021.3' = 1000000,
    '2021.4' = 1000000
  )
  
  budgets_df <- create_sample_df(budgets)
  
  # eventually use distinct budgets for each, just demo right now
  output$budgets_df_dh <- render_dt(data = budgets_df,
                                    rownames = FALSE,
                                    list(target = 'column',
                                         disable = list(columns = c(0, 2:4))))
  
  dh_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('budgets_df_dh')
  
  observeEvent(input$budgets_df_dh_cell_edit, {
    
    info = input$budgets_df_dh_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    v = info$value
    budgets[[i]] <<- v %>% as.numeric()
    budgets_df <<- create_sample_df(budgets)
    replaceData(dh_proxy, budgets_df, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I set it so that the user can amend the Spend field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to off-set j by 1.  Also, I created a reactiveValues object to show that the changes have taken effect, and is available on the server side for further analysis.  It is printed as second table below your table.

```
# generates an example df based on inputed budgets
create_sample_df <- function(budgets) {
  data.frame(cohort = seq('2020-10-01' %>% ymd, '2021-12-31' %>% ymd, by = '1 days')) %>%
    mutate(Quarter = quarter(cohort, with_year = T)) %>%
    add_count(Quarter) %>%
    mutate(DailyBudget = budgets[Quarter %>% as.character] %>% unlist / n) %>%
    group_by(Quarter) %>%
    mutate(Revenue = DailyBudget + rnorm(n(), mean = 0, sd = DailyBudget / 5)) %>%
    summarise(Spend = sum(DailyBudget),
              Revenue = sum(Revenue),
              .groups = 'drop') %>%
    mutate(Profit = dollar(Revenue - Spend),
           Payback = percent(Revenue / Spend),
           Spend = dollar(Spend),
           Revenue = dollar(Revenue)) %>%
    mutate(Quarter = as.character(Quarter)) # do this last keep ordering of quarters
}



# render DT
render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}


# UI ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Velocity Spend & Return Calculator')
HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  menuItem("dh", tabName = "dh", icon = icon("dashboard"))
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dh",
            h2("DH Estimator"),
            HTML("Adjust spend column for calculations"),
            DT::DTOutput('budgets_df_dh'),
            DTOutput("tb1")

    )
  )
)


ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


# Server ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  DF1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
  # Initial budgets, eventually set to come from dropdowns or user input
  budgets <- list(
    '2020.4' = 1000000,
    '2021.1' = 1000000,
    '2021.2' = 1000000,
    '2021.3' = 1000000,
    '2021.4' = 1000000
  )

  budgets_df <- reactive({
    bud <- create_sample_df(budgets)
    DF1$data <- bud
    bud
  })

  # eventually use distinct budgets for each, just demo right now
  output$budgets_df_dh <- render_dt(data = budgets_df(),
                                    rownames = FALSE,
                                    list(target = 'cell',
                                         disable = list(columns = c(0, 2:4))) )

  #dh_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('budgets_df_dh')

  observeEvent(input$budgets_df_dh_cell_edit, {
    
    info = input$budgets_df_dh_cell_edit
    str(info)
    i = info$row
    j = info$col + 1
    v = info$value

    DF1$data[i,j] <<- DT::coerceValue(v , DF1$data[i, j]) 

  })
  output$tb1 <- renderDT(DF1$data)

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you, this does allow me to edit the cell per my question. I noticed though, that the newly generated DF after a user changes the spend column has the same Revenue data. Expectation was that this would update since revenue is a function of spend during `create_sample_df()`. Any ideas there?

Comment: Put another way when the user edits the spend column I need to re-render `budgets_df()` to include the upated values

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the dependency there.  I will check now.

Comment: To clarify, I had a piece of code like this within `observEvent()` `budgets[[i]] <<- v %>% str_replace_all('\\$|,', '') %>% as.numeric`. This upates the list of initial budgets where they are all 1M to be the new value inputed by the user. Then, when calling `create_sample_df()`, it makes use of the now updated variable budgets. Any help much appreciated

Comment: @DougFir, I tried last few hours.  It seems like your function might require some adjustment.  As per you OP, datatable not allowing to edit cells has been answered.  The modified datatable is available on the server side as DF1$data.  You need to pass the second column information on Spend (say, `DF1$data[,2]`) and obtain the output dataframe from `create_sample_df()`.  Defining `spend <- as.numeric(as.character(DF1$data[,2]))` will give no errors.  Your function gives only column1, all others are blank.  Perhaps you should post this as a separate question and someone else can answer it.

Comment: HI, thanks for your help here. Yes, I will post separatley

Comment: Please note that your function works fine if I call it separately, outside shiny app. Somehow it is giving me blank columns in this app.

Comment: I made a new post with slimmed down code in case it's of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63892744/upate-datatable-based-on-user-input-inclue-upate-of-corresponding-columns-not